# R: how to use "get/assign" function in foreach?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use "get/assign" function inside "foreach".
A simplified case is here:

a1, a2, a3,...an (n can be any predefined number) are the objects saved in the global environment, and b is an array inside the loop used to store the objects.

*More complicated case could be a1, a2, a3,...an are large matrices, and try to use "get" plus index to retrieve cell value, such as   get(a1)[index]. The "sum" process could be a more complicated computation based on the array b.

My code is:

```
c <- foreach (j = 1:3) %dopar% {
    for (i in 1:n){
        b[i] <- get(paste("a",i,sep=""))
    }
    sum(b)
}
```

I'm expecting the results like this:

```
for (j in 1:3) {
    for (i in 1:3){
        b[i] <- get(paste("a",i,sep=""))
    }
    c[i] = sum(b)
}
```

However, the a1,a2,a3 have not been found

Comment: In your case, you need to export the global variables to each worker: `registerDoParallel(cl, cores=2); clusterExport(cl, c("a1", "a2", "a3"));`

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for you to use `get` and `assign`. The `ai` should be together in one data structure and not separate.

Comment: Hi @Roland, sorry for the confusion here, this is just a simplified case. If each of the a's is a big matrix (such as, raster image) and i is the number of coregistered matrices (i is various depending on operator's setting), are you still suggesting combine those matrices together and send into foreach?

Comment: If you want to iterate over objects, put them together in a list and iterate over that list. `get` and `assign` are only needed if you do complex stuff with environments, which is clearly beyond your level of expertise.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you necessarily have a problem with `get` inside the foreach block. You have two loops here, so it's not clear where `b` is created. This is true for both code blocks. Also, `foreach` should be `foreach(j=1:3)`

Try adding `b <- c()` before the `for(i in 1:3)` statement.

```
library(foreach)
a1 <- 1
a2 <- 2
a3 <- 3
c <- foreach(j=1:3) %dopar% {
    b <- c()
        for (i in 1:3) {
            b[i] <- get(paste("a",i,sep=""))
        }
    sum(b)
}
```